# Преобразовать синхронный метод с callback функцией в асинхронный

Tags: c#, callback, асинхронность

Есть метод следующего вида:

```
public void Save(Stream stream)
{
    SaveCallback saveCallback =
        delegate(byte[] data)
        {
            try
            {
                stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                return true;
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
        };

    if (!NativeMethods.Save(saveCallback))
        throw new Exception();
}
```

Т.е. некий `NativeMethods.Save` вызывает callback, передавая туда пакет байт для сохранения. Вызовов callback может быть несколько (несколько пакетов).

Хотелось бы по-возможности преобразовать данный метод в асинхронный. С учётом того, что сигнатуры `NativeMethods.Save` и `SaveCallback` не могут быть изменены, как правильнее всего это сделать?

Варианты, которые приходят в голову:

- просто обернуть всё в `Task.Run()`
- обернуть в `Task.Run()` вызов `NativeMethods.Save`, и дополнительно
  обернуть в `Task.Run()` тело saveCallback (это позволит использовать
  `stream.WriteAsync`)
- быть может здесь возможно использование `TaskCompletionSource`
  каким-либо образом, на манер того как EAP (*Event-based Asynchronous
  Pattern*) можно преобразовать в `Task`, если да - то как?

Или вообще не стоит этого делать? Первые два варианта, как я понимаю не дадут *true async*, надежда на третий вариант.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тут проблема вот в чем. `SaveCallback` возвращает некоторое булево значение - которое `NativeMethods.Save` как-то по-своему использует. В такой ситуации `SaveCallback` сделать асинхронным невозможно в принципе!

Лучшее, что можно сделать в такой ситуации - это обернуть вызов `NativeMethods` в `Task.Run`. Но и это еще не все: наверняка же `NativeMethods` еще и хочет работать в однопоточном режиме. А значит - надо как-то избегать вызова двух методов `Save` одновременно.

Для этого можно воспользоваться классом [`AsyncLock`](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/wiki/AsyncLock):

```
static readonly AsyncLock _lock = new AsyncLock();

// ...

public Task Save(Stream stream)
{
  return Task.Run(async () =>
  {
    using (await _lock.LockAsync())
    {
      Exception ex = null;
      if (!NativeMethods.Save(data =>
      {
        try
        {
          stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
          return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex2)
        {
          ex = ex2;
          return false;
        }
      })) throw ex ?? new Exception();
    }
  });
}
```

Да, вы совершенно правы, такая асинхронность не является "настоящей". Но если асинхронное сохранение нужно непременно, то при таких ограничениях это - лучший вариант.

Comment: А что такая «настоящая» асинхронность и чем эта не подходит под эту категорию? Кроме того, если `NativeMethods.Save` не является потокобезопасной, то такой подход всё равно не спасёт. Что если кто-то вызовет эту функцию в другом потоке?

Comment: @ixSci Смысл защиты - в том, чтобы договориться не вызывать эту функцию иначе чем через обертку.

Comment: @ixSci настоящая асинхронная функция - это функция, которая нигде не делает блокирующих вызовов.

Comment: Насколько я вижу, функция `Save` не делает блокирующих вызовов.

Comment: @ixSci а как же `stream.Write`? Он уже перестал блокировать поток? :)

Comment: Он блокирует какой-то там другой поток. `Save` возвращается «мгновенно»

Comment: @ixSci настоящая асинхронная функция - это функция, которая нигде не делает блокирующих вызовов, *в том числе в другом потоке*.

Comment: Ну так `Save` не делает никаких блокирующих вызовов, или Вы с этим не согласны?

Comment: @ixSci прочитайте, пожалуйста, мои ответы еще раз.

Comment: Я прочитал их несколько раз, я понимаю к чему Вы клоните, я просто пытаюсь показать, что Вы клоните к абсурду.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36498/discussion-between-pavel-mayorov-and-ixsci).